# API to Retrieve created questions without any attempt from Moodle

Tags: java, postman, moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

Retrieve all questions just created by user (that are not replied = without any attempt) is what I'm looking for.

It's possible to retrieve the different attempts of a question (already replied = with attempts) through **mod_quiz_get_user_attempts**, but it isn't possible with questions without any reply or attempt.

Basing on [Moodle Documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions), I didn't found the right function.
Any suggestion will be appreciated and thanks in advance.